# geocoder.getLatLng() method not showing all the addresses on google map?

Tags: asp.net

I have latitude and longitude values in the database columns(More that 20), so i am just grabing those values and passing them to geocoder.getLatLng() method to display them as markers. But this method not pretty fast, I kept this method inside a loop to run through all the values from database, But not all the addresses are showing up everytime I refresh the page its missing some addresses.Here is my code, please give me some suggestions and tell how to set the time out.

```
        script += " var location = \"\"+ latitude +\", \"+ longitude +\"\";\n";

        script += " geocoder.getLatLng( \n";
        script += " location,function(point) \n";
        script += " {if (point) { \n";
        //script += "       alert(point);\n";
        script += "     var icon = new GIcon(baseIcon);\n";
        script += "     icon.image = \"_gfx/gmap/marker\" + (iconNum) + \".png\";\n";
        script += "     var LocImage = new Image();\n";
        script += "     LocImage.src =\"Modules/ShowImage.aspx?imageid=\"+ ImageID +\"\";\n";
        script += "     var marker = new GMarker(point, icon);\n";
        script += "     map.addOverlay(marker); \n";
        script += "     GEvent.addListener(marker, \"click\", function() {\n";
        script += "         marker.openInfoWindowHtml(\"<div class='facility_map'><a href='\" +detailLink[index]+ \"' class='facility_name'>\" + name + \"</a><br />\" +((ImageID!= \"0\")?\"<img src='\" +LocImage.src + \"' class='markerimg' width='170' height='180' />\":\"\")+ \"<br /><a href=\"+ link[index] +\" target='_blank'>\" + displayAddress + \"</a><br />\" +((PhoneNum != \"\")?\"<b>Phone:</b>\"+PhoneNum+\"\":\"\")+ \"<br />\" + AllAmenities + \"<b>Capacity:</b>\" + Capacities + \"</div>\");\n";
        script += " })\n";
        script += "     return marker;\n";
        script += " }\n";
```

Comment: Not related to the question, but why not put this function in a javascript file? It hurts my eyes and is not dynamic as far i can see.

Comment: Here is the code to add marker in the javascript

Comment: var location = (latitude, longitude);  
   geocoder.getLatLng( 
   location,function(point)
   { if (point) {
    var icon = new GIcon(baseIcon);
    icon.image = "_gfx/gmap/marker" + (iconNum) + ".png";
    var marker = new GMarker(point, icon);   
    map.addOverlay(marker); 
    }
   });